# Edit a silkscreen over a gerber file in Altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium, gerber

I have some gerber files that are perfect, except the legend. I would like to include some useful information on the top silkscreen.

is it possible to edit a new PCB using a gerber file as background in altium?

Comment: Could you please clarify the question. I think you mean "Is it possible edit the gerber in order to create a new PCB with this information?". Is this right?

Comment: I would like to create a new PCB document, using the information from the gerber file or something similar, to create a complete new silkscreen, based on the top/bottom layers, etc.

Comment: You can't create (or updated) a PCB file from a Gerber file. As far as I know that´s impossible. The workflow is  in the other direction. You generate the gerber files from a PCB file.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, that you want to edit the silk screen gerber without changing the original pcb file, yes, it's possible.

You use Altium's included CAM editor (CAMtastic). Stack Exchange won't let me link the manual section because it's a numeric URL, but you can find it easily.

Of course next time you generate the output job (because of a revision, say), you'll have to repeat the editing, so it's usually not the best way to do things.

[image]

Comment: it is a gerber file from another software.. i would like to create a complete new silkscreen using the PCB editor

Comment: The PCB editor does not input Gerber files, so you cannot use that part of Altium. CAMtastic is really a separate program, and it will input and output Gerber files (valid files from anywhere).

Answer (score 3):

You can view or edit any gerber files regardless the CAD system there were generated with. You should use a Gerber Editor. There are few of them in the market.

All you need is edit the silkscreen gerber and include in it the new information. The steps will be something like this:

- Import the silkscreen gerber into the Gerber Editor.
- Edit it (Insert text)
- Save the changes.

For example, you can try with Pentalogix ViewMate. There is a free version. (I have no link with this product.)

Below it's shown a capture. I have imported a silkscreen gerber and, with the menu Insert text, I have added a new text in the layer.

[image]